# Do I need to enable Remote Database Access?

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel, remote-server

I'm building an application which automatically updates an online MySQL database with results from a local computer.

I plan to run the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10723742/773263)

```
C:>mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE > database.sql
C:>mysql -hHOST -pPORT -uUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASE < database.sql
```

Would doing this require me to add my IP address to the Remote Database Access Hosts section of my cpanel?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote Database Access from a local computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898543/remote-database-access-from-a-local-computer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enable remote access to your mysql database server:[enable remote access](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)