# MySql C# - access with MyPhpAdmin but not with app

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm developing an app with C# and I need to access MySql database in my university server. They provided me one login and password. With they, I can access the MySql via PhpMyAdmin, but when I try to connect with my app, the following error occurs:

"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

I thought that could be the privileges of the user. But I'm not sure. So, what could be? With the possible solutions I can ask them to correct.
My connection code:

```
server = "server";
            database = "database";
            uid = "id";
            password = "pass";
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" +     "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
```

Thanks a lot! I'm sorry for my bad English. =(

Comment: Are you sure the university allows remote connections to the server?  MySQL will usually provide a better error if the user doesn't have permissions, but if the port is blocked by a firewall this behavior makes sense.

Comment: I'll aks them. So, if the port is blocked I can access with the phpmyadmin but not with the app? I'm new in MySql, so I'm looking for a cause to be able to ask them the correction. =) Thanks!

Comment: Yes sir.  I'm willing to bet that because it is a school that the port is blocked.

Comment: I'm gonna ask them to try it and as soon as possible I post a feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql server's default port is 3306. You need to add a connectionstring in web.config and use them all over in your web-app.

As Meda written in her answer you need to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 it must be the ip of your server where you actually host your mysql database. remember that remote access must be enabled (on your university server) if you provide the IP to access the mysql database.

Tried these thing will surely fix your issue.

Comment: The port was blocked. Issue fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use MySQL with my C# projects and I define the host value as:

- localhost or 127.0.0.1
- an IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
- a host url (my.dbserver.com)

here is a working `MySQL` connection string:

```
<add name="connectionString"
     connectionString="server=xx.xx.xx.xx;database=yyyyy;
                                                 User Id=zzzzzz;Password=**********;"
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Comment: I've tried with the host url and the IP address but still doesn't work :/

Comment: like the other said in the comments, you need to make sure your IP calling this code is authorized

Comment: @RafaelCampos check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900107/do-i-need-to-enable-remote-database-access